# XSLT Logic Overwrite a temporary variable

Tags: xslt

How we can achieve below logic.

The UniqueID is the temporary variable.PALLET_NUMBER  is coming from input.

if PALLET_NUMBER!=NULL then

UniqueID=substring (PALLET_NUMBER, 10)

if PALLET_NUMBER =NULL then

UniqueID=substring (CARTON_NUMBER, 7)

we can get the value of UniqueID from the above two conditions.These things happen in iteration loop.How we can overwrite the  UniqueID temporary variable.

bacause later There is a condition we need to put like

```
<foreach>   
 If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID then

        <Some code>
        <IF>
</foreach>
```

Comment: you cannot overwrite variables in XSLT

Comment: Also if you post your xml input / xslt you tried using and wanted output we can provide more help.

Comment: XSLT is a functional language, not a procedural one, and you can't really think in terms of "iteration" and "variables" like you may be used to in other languages.  If you can edit your question to include a sample of your input and desired output we can give you some pointers on how to achieve the mapping in a more functional way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite variable in xslt.

You may want to look up xslt extension functions to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

As Treemonkey, says, it's not possible to overwrite variables, but you can achieve something like you describe using recursion:

Suppose you had something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="my/node/isNamed/something" />
```

You could do this instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="items" select="my/node/isNamed/something" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="$items[1]">
  <xsl:with-param name="remainder" select="$items[position() > 1" />
</xsl:apply-templates>

<!-- Separate template -->
<xsl:template match="something">
  <xsl:param name="remainder" />
  <xsl:param name="lastId" />

  <xsl:variable name="uniqueId" select="..." />
  <!-- Contents of the xsl:for-each -->

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$remainder[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="remainder" select="$remainder[position() > 1]" />
    <xsl:with-param name="lastId" select="$uniqueId" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```